# How to recursively call a function using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a typing application. I am matching the typed input in the textbox after the user presses the space key and clearing the textbox. But, how to do for multiple p tags as I don't want to use so many if else.This is my first p1 tag and have around multiple p tags. I need to iterate this function for other successive tags also.

```
function search(ele) {
            document.getElementById("p1").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
            if (event.keyCode === 32) {
                if (ele.value == "ਪਰ") {
                    document.getElementById("p1").style.backgroundColor = "green";
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById("p1").style.backgroundColor = "red";
                }
                document.getElementById("textvalue").value = "";
            }
        }

 <span style="margin-left:8px;"> <input type="text" id="textvalue" size="50" onkeydown="search(this)"  /></span>
```

Below are the p tags:

```
 <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <p id="p1">ਪਰ </p>

                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <p id="p2">ਕਰ </pid="p1">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <p id="p3">ਤਕ </p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <p id="p4">ਤਪ </p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <p id="p5">ਚਰਚ </p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <p id="p6">ਰਕਤ </p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <p id="p7">ਪਰਤ </p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <p id="p8">ਪਰਕੋ </p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <p id="p9">ਚਤਰ </p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <p id="p10">ਤਰਕ </p>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <p id="p11">ਚਟਪਟ</p>
                            </td>


                        </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you give a specific example? Which multiple p tags?

Comment: If i understood your question correctly, you just want to use `class` instead of `ID`. Then you use the selector `document.getElementsByClassName('myclass')` and loop over it.

Comment: Parameterized the search function, pass the p1 tag and the search value as params and call this function on which ever element your want to

Comment: Loop through `document.querySelectorAll("p")` and do all these operations on each element

Comment: @CertainPerformance this code is working for my p1 id and now i want to iterate it for remaining p ids also.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what are you trying to achieve, but you are probably looking for something like this:

```js
function search(ele) {
  if (event.keyCode === 32) {
    let ps = document.getElementsByClassName('pstyled');
    for (let i = 0; i < ps.length; i++) {
      ps[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow"; // Not sure whats the yellow here for, since the element will be either green or red anyways.
      if (ele.value == ps[i].textContent) {
        ps[i].style.backgroundColor = "green";
      } else {
        ps[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
      }
    }
    document.getElementById("textvalue").value = "";
    event.preventDefault(); //prevents adding space after the function is run
  }
}
```

```html
<span style="margin-left:8px;"> <input type="text" id="textvalue" size="50" onkeydown="search(this)"  /></span>

<table>
  <tr>
      <td>
          <p id="p1" class="pstyled">ਪਰ</p>
      </td>
      <td>
          <p id="p2" class="pstyled">ਕਰ</p>
      </td>
      <td>
          <p id="p3" class="pstyled">ਤਕ</p>
      </td>
      <td>
          <p id="p4" class="pstyled">ਤਪ</p>
      </td>
      <td>
          <p id="p5" class="pstyled">ਚਰਚ</p>
      </td>
      <td>
          <p id="p6" class="pstyled">ਰਕਤ</p>
      </td>
      <td>
          <p id="p7" class="pstyled">ਪਰਤ</p>
      </td>
      <td>
          <p id="p8" class="pstyled">ਪਰਕੋ</p>
      </td>
      <td>
          <p id="p9" class="pstyled">ਚਤਰ</p>
      </td>
      <td>
          <p id="p10" class="pstyled">ਤਰਕ</p>
      </td>
      <td>
          <p id="p11" class="pstyled">ਚਟਪਟ</p>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As i said in comment:

- add class to each p element (technically you could query by tag, but you might have many more `<p>` tags on page)
- use `document.getElementsByClassName()` which returns an array of elements
- loop over the array